# Видео-курсы по jQuery и JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброй ночи! Очень нравится технология jQuery, да и JavaScript в принципе, но я к сожалению не встречал достойных видео-курсов ни по jQuery, ни по JavaScript. Если кто знает хорошие видео-курсы, по этим технологиям, на русском или английском языках - поделитесь пожалуйста ссылками или расскажите как найти. Заранее благодарен.

P.S. Предпочтительнее русские видео-курсы, но также, с удовольствием, посмотрю и английские.

Comment: Сложно зайди на rutracker и скачать видеокурсы где найбольшее количество сидов(а значит они самые толковые)?

Comment: >  где найбольшее количество сидов(а значит они самые толковые)

Загадочная логика ))

Comment: Deonis 100% с Вами согласен!

Comment: Я один не выношу видеокурсы и люблю книги и доки?

Comment: @Construct, Вы не одиноки. Я ради интереса посмотрел один по С++ (просто видео с лекции) и несколько по методам сортировки и понял, что это пустая трата времени.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JavaScript & AJAX](http://net.tutsplus.com/category/tutorials/javascript-ajax/?tag=videos).

Answer (score 2):

Ну из ввсех более менее популярных курсов могу отметить курсы [Е.Попов jquery + javascript](http://www.rutor.org/torrent/73666/javascript-jquery-dlja-nachinajuwih-v-videoformate-2010-pc) и курсы [Специалист javascript,jquery и тд](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3856910)

Answer (score 1):

Евгений Попов реально рулит)
сам учился по этому видеокурсу)

Comment: @denisKlimenko, тёзка, тс-с-с... О Попове тут нужно говорить шёпотом, иначе могут камнями забросать ))

Comment: @denisKlimenko, видимо в результате этих курсов Вы задали вопрос "jQuery, соединение массива" ?

Comment: ну там же не полный материал))